# Utf - 8 character in the url parameter of the .open() method of xmlhttp request object

Tags: javascript, ajax, utf-8

I've got a web service in which try to find in a big database all the  elements  that start with those three letters entered in the client side html page:

Here is the code in Java - for my web service

```
public class locselall 
{



public String FindEl(String myel ) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{

    String strXml = "<response>";

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    try 
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/plovdivbizloca", "postgres", "tan");
    }

    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    Statement mystmt = null;
    String selectQuery = "select biz_subject from pl_biz WHERE biz_subject ILIKE '"+ myel + "%'";

    try {
        mystmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet mysr = mystmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = mysr.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int numberrow = 0;
        strXml += "<rows>";

        while (mysr.next()) 
        {
            strXml += "<row id= '" + numberrow + "'>";
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) 
            {
                String elementname = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                String elementValue = mysr.getString(i);
                strXml += "<colunm colname='" + elementname
                        + "' colvalue='" + elementValue + "'/>";
            }
            numberrow++;
            strXml += "</row>";
        }
        strXml += "</rows>";

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {

    }
    strXml += "</response>";

    return strXml;
}
```

}

And there is no problem when i type in the browser

```
http://localhost:9091/locselall/services/locselall/FindEl?myel=СИТ
```

Everything works;

---

And here is the client side html page

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
function triming()
{

var strInput= document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
//var newstr = strInput.replace(/[\p{L}]/gi, '');
var newstr = strInput.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FF0-9]/gi, '');

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //var xmlObj = xmlhttp.responseXML;   
                //var textXML = xmlObj.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;





            }

        }


        var url = "http://localhost:9091/locselall/services/locselall/FindEl?myel="+ newstr;
        alert (url);

        document.getElementById('pr').innerHTML = url;

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 





}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type= "text" id="txtInput"   />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" onClick = "triming();"/>
<div id="pr"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

As you see i have an alert for the url and it's exactly the same as the url which i typed in the browser to test my web service - 
but this time i don't get any records; 
The server returns only   which means that when it gets to the statement to select it cannot be executed

I think the problem is that my variable newstr should hold utf - 8 element and it's not properly send to the server. and as a result it cannot select any records!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is, when you go to url like `http://localhost:9091/locselall/services/locselall/FindEl?myel=СИТ` in a browser like Chrome, it will actually make a request to this URL:

```
http://localhost:9091/locselall/services/locselall/FindEl?myel=%D0%A1%D0%98%D0%A2
```

To ensure this happens in code as well, you must use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var url = "http://localhost:9091/locselall/services/locselall/FindEl?myel="+ 
          encodeURIComponent(newstr);
```